# Cant adjust Opacity of image loaded as layer

Tags: gimpfu

If I open an existing image as a base image, and a second image as a layer to add to the base image, is there a way to adjust the opacity of the layer image?

```
base_image = pdb.gimp_file_load(img, img)
layer_1 = pdb.gimp_file_load_layer(base_img, layer_image)

base_image.add_layer(layer_1)
```

I know you can set opacity level when calling `pdb.gimp_layer_new(...)`but haven't found a way to adjust an image loaded as a layer. Is script_fu a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

layer_1.opacity = 50 #1-100

found decent docs here:
https://www.gimp.org/docs/python/